# How to avoid texture bleeding in a texture atlas?

Tags: opengl, textures, interpolation, texture-atlas, mipmaps

In my game there is a Minecraft-like terrain made out of cubes. I generate a vertex buffer from the voxel data and use a texture atlas for looks of different blocks:

[image: texture atlas for voxel based terrain]

The problem is that the texture of distant cubes interpolates with adjacent tiles in the texture atlas. That results in lines of wrong colors between cubes (you may need to view the screenshot below at its full size to see the graphical flaws):

[image: screenshot of terrain with stripes of the wrong color]

For now I use these interpolation settings but I tried every combination and even `GL_NEAREST` without mipmapping doesn't provide better results.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

I also tried added an offset in the texture coordinates to pick a slightly smaller area of the tile but since the unwanted effect depends on the distance to the camera this cannot solve the problem completely. At far distances the stripes occur anyway.

How can I solve this texture bleeding? Since using a texture atlas is popular technique there might be a common approach. Sadly, for some reasons explained in the comments, I cannot change to different textures or texture arrays.

Comment: The problem lies with mipmapping - your texture coordinates may work well for the biggest mip level, but as things get further away, the bordering tiles blend together. You can fight this by not using mipmaps (probably not a good idea), growing your guard zones (area between tiles), growing the guard zones dynamically in a shader based on mip level (tricky), do something strange while generating mipmaps (can't think of anything though).. I've never tackled this problem myself though, but there's stuff to start with.. =)

Comment: As I said sadly turning off mipmapping doesn't solve the problem. Without mipmaps it will either interpolate linear `GL_LINEAR` which gives a similar result or pick the nearest pixel `GL_NEAREST` which anyhow also results in stripes between blocks. Last mentioned option decreases but not eliminates the pixel flaw.

Comment: One solution is to use a format that have generated mipmaps, then you could create thees mipmaps your self and correct the error.

Another solution is to force a specific mipmap level in your fragmentshader when you are sampling the texture.

Another solution is to fill the mipmaps with the first mipmap.
In other words, when you are creating your texture, you can just add subimages to that particular image, containing the same data.

Comment: I had this problem before and it was solved by adding 1-2 pixel padding in your atlas between each different texture.

Comment: @sharethis: I know you say disabling mipmapping doesn't solve it but that screenshot is definitely showing multiple mip-levels with the problem only on the more distant level.

Comment: @Kylotan. The problem is about texture resizing regardless of if it is done by mipmaps, linear interpolation or nearest pixel picking.

Comment: @RubberMallet. I wrapped each tile of my texture atlas in each direction its half size as described in [this article](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=61602) and it become better. But some seems are still there which I hope can be concealed by antialiasing.

Comment: @sharethis: what you've posted is clearly a mipmap issue, not a sampling issue. The system generates mip levels across the logical boundary of your subtexture because it knows nothing about it. If there's no bleed at each mip level and your tiles are seamless then any type of sampling and interpolation should work.

Comment: @Kylotan. Sadly there are stripes even without mipmapping at all, I do not know why. What I will try is to manually generate the mipmaps at initialization time inside the logical boundaries of my tiles but therefore I might need to find a graphics library.

Comment: I think this is due to how the system is downscaling the texture in your min filter. It may look like a mipmap issue since it's exaggerated by distance but that to me indicates resampling rules set in the min filter?

Comment: Have you looked at this article? http://gregs-blog.com/2008/01/17/opengl-texture-filter-parameters-explained/

Comment: @RubberMallet. I tried `GL_LINEAR`, `GL_NEAREST` and the ones using mipmapping. I think either scaling down by mipmapping, by linear interpolation or by picking the nearest pixel causes the artifacts.

Comment: Can you use aniso at all? GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT that might help some..

Comment: @RubberMallet: the screenshot clearly shows that the problem only starts on the second visible mip level. If there truly is a problem that is not related to mip mapping, I'd like to see a new screenshot that demonstrates this. Still, the original poster should try GL_CLAMP or GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE instead of GL_REPEAT and see if that helps.

Comment: I also was going to suggest CLAMP like @Kylotan, i never use REPEAT unless for a specific reason. I see the same thing but if its still there without Mipmap enabled, its a resampling issue causing the artificat, not matter what level mip is being used/not used.

Comment: @Kylotan. I updated the question with screenshots at different settings.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the rather odd software texture-wrapping system is causing the problem. Most likely your UV values have not been adjusted to take it into account.

Comment: @Kylotan. Of course they are. I double tested them. Because the texture coordinates are normalized (from 0 to 1) instead of per pixel, the result is just what I expected. If I am very far and the texture is scaled (either trough mipmapping or immediate interpolation) to say 2x2 pixels, normalized texture coordinates must pick the wrong colors. But sadly I still do not know how to approach this issue.

Comment: Textures don't get scaled that way except through mip-mapping. If mip mapping is off there's no good reason it would sample texels outside the area you specify if you use GL_NEAREST. Either it's a driver bug or you're doing something wrong. Personally at this stage I would advise dumping the texture atlases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023400/opengl-es-texture-coordinates-slightly-off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After struggling a lot with this issue, I finally came up with a solution.

To use both, a texture atlas and mipmapping, I need to perform the downsampling myself, because OpenGL would otherwise interpolate over the boundaries of tiles in the atlas. Moreover I needed to set the right texture parameters, because interpolating between mipmaps would also cause texture bleeding.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

With these parameters, no bleeding occurs.

There is one thing you have to notice when providing custom mipmaps. Since it doesn't make sense to shrink the atlas even if each tile is already `1x1`, the maximal mipmap level must be set according to what you provide.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 7); // pick mipmap level 7 or lower
```

Thanks for all other answers and very helpful comments! By the way I still do not know how to use linear up scaling, but I guess there is no way.

Comment: good to know you got it solved. You should mark this answer as the correct one instead of mine.

Comment: mipmapping is a technique exclusively for downsampling, which makes no sense for upsampling. The idea is that if you're going to draw a small triangle, it would take a lot of time to sample a large texture just to get a few pixels out of it, so you pre-downsample it and use the appropriate mip level when drawing small triangles. For larger triangles, using anything different from the larger mip level doesn't make sense, so it is an error to do something like `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);`

Comment: @PandaPajama. You are right, I corrected my answer. To set `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` causes bleeding not for the reason of mipmapping, but for the reason of interpolation. So in this case it is equivalent to `GL_LINEAR` since the lowest mipmap level is used anyway.

Comment: @danijar - Can you explain in more detail how you perform the downsampling yourself, and how you tell OpenGL where (and when) to use the downsampled atlas?

Comment: @TimKane Split atlas into the tiles. For each mipmap level,  downsample the tiles bilinearly, combine them, and upload that to the GPU specifying the mipmap level as parameter to `glTexImage2D()`. The GPU automatically chooses the correct level based on objects size on screen.

Answer (score 41):

Okay, I think you have two problems going on here.

The first problem is with mipmapping. In general, you don't want to naively mix atlasing with mipmapping, because unless all your subtextures are exactly 1x1 pixel sized, you will experience texture bleeding. Adding padding will simply move the problem to a lower mip level.

As a rule of thumb, for 2D, which is where you usually do atlasing, you don't mipmap; while for 3D, which is where you mipmap, you don't atlas (actually, you skin in such a way that bleeding won't be a problem)

However, what I think is going on with your program right now is that you're probably not using the correct texture coordinates, and because of that your textures are bleeding.

Let's suppose an 8x8 texture. You're probably getting the top-left quarter by using uv coordinates of (0,0) to (0.5, 0.5):

[image: Incorrect mapping]

And the problem is that at u-coordinate 0.5, the sampler will interpolate the destination fragment using half of the left texel and half of the right texel. The same will happen at u-coordinate 0, and the same for v-coordinates. This is because you're addressing the borders between texels, and not the centers.

What you should do instead is address the center of each texel. In this example, these are the coordinates you want to use:

[image: Correct mapping]

In this case, you will always be sampling the center of each texel and you should not get any bleeding... *Unless you use mipmapping, in which case you will always get bleeding starting on the mip level where the scaled subtexture doesn't neatly fit inside the pixel grid*.

To generalize, if you want to access a specific texel, the coordinates are calculated as:

```
function get_texel_coords(x, y, tex_width, tex_height)
    u = (x + 0.5) / tex_width
    v = (y + 0.5) / tex_height
    return u, v
end
```

This is called "half pixel correction". There's a more detailed explanation in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you're interested.

Comment: Your explanation sounds very promising. Sadly since I have to video card at the moment, I cannot implement it yet. I will do so if the repaired card arrives. And I will calculate the mipmaps of the atlas on my own without interpolating over the boundaries of tiles then.

Comment: @sharethis If you definitely have to atlas, make sure your subtextures have sizes in powers of 2, so you can limit bleeding to the lowest mip levels. If you do so, you don't really need to hand craft your own mipmaps.

Comment: Even PoT sized textures can have bleed artifacts though, because the bilinear filtering can sample across those boundaries. (At least in the implementations I've seen.) As for the half-pixel correction, should that apply in this case? If I wanted to map his rock texture for example, surely that will always be 0.0 to 0.25 along the U and V coordinates?

Comment: @Kylotan If your texture size is even, and all the subtextures have even sizes and are located at even coordinates, bilinear filtering when halving the texture size will not mix between subtextures. Generalize for powers of two (if you're seeing artifacts, you're probably using bicubic, not bilinear filtering). Regarding half-pixel correction, it is necessary, because 0.25 is not the rightmost texel, but the middle point between both subtextures. To put it into perspective, imagine that you are the rasterizer: what is the color of the texture at  (0.00, 0.25)?

Comment: @PandaPajama: My terminology was incorrect - bilinear wouldn't have artifacts (as you say) but I'm pretty sure I've encountered auto-generated mip-maps that did use a more complex filter. As for the half-pixel correction, I'm afraid I still don't understand: I don't mind that u=0.25 is between 2 texels because I'd intend it to be between 2 pixels too. So I would think that if I wanted to render just the top 1/16th of that image I'd want UVs from (0,0) to (0.25, 0.25). I don't ever want to sample individual texels, just subsections of the texture.

Comment: @Kylotan well, maybe you don't want to, but sampling texels is the only thing the rasterizer knows how to do. Technically speaking, you don't strictly need to sample at the centers, you just have to sample at a texture coordinate strictly less than 0.25 to unambiguously let the sampler know which texel to use. Sampling at the centers also has the advantage that your floating point coordinates will be exact and immune from rounding errors (if the texture size is a power of two).

Comment: @Kylotan suppose you create a triangle, and set texture coordinates for each vertex. For vanilla texture mapping, you just pass the texture coordinates through the vertex shader, and they get interpolated across the entire triangle. The rasterizer then gets the interpolated texture coordinates for each pixel to be drawn. That is the coordinate you get at the fragment shader, which you use to sample the texture. If you're using nearest-neighbor, sampling at a coordinate less than 0.25 will get the correct texel, while with bilinear, anything farther than the center of the texel will bleed.

Comment: @PandaPajama: this doesn't change my understanding though - you usually specify the UVs for the edges of what you want to render, not the middle - so you don't expect it to take a sample directly from position 0 or 0.25 when you specify those values. The fact they're between texels is expected and not an issue. (And rounding errors or precision problems shouldn't be an issue for powers of two either.) So I don't understand what this would be addressing. If what you said was correct then you'd expect the 0.0-1.0 case to bleed too, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Kylotan are you sure it doesn't bleed when you set the texture coordinates to 0.0, 1.0? Try setting the sampler wrapping mode to repeat, and you will see it bleeding from the opposite side. http://www.imageupload.org/en/file/247100/bleeding.png.html

Comment: @PandaPajama: But that shows an equal amount of wrapping on all 4 edges, which supports my theory of the filtering taking samples from over a wider area (eg. more than just linear interpolation between 2 adjacent texels). If it was just an offset issue, you'd expect to see wrapping only on one side, or much more on one side than the other.

Comment: @Kylotan bilinear filtering works by interpolating the 4 texels closest to the sampling location according to their distance to the sampling location. Bleeding occurs when at least one of those 4 texels is not part of the desired sampling area, and starts at the half pixel border in all four directions. That's why you must reduce the texture mapping by half a texel in all four borders to eliminate bleeding.

Comment: @PandaPajama: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation and image!

Comment: You are right, both half pixel shifting and mipmapping are the reasons for my texture atlas to bleed. I am still not sure how to solve to problem. Half pixel correction breaks tileable textures from a close look as their texture's outer pixels are smaller in the scene. In addition, I have to come up with my own mipmapping algorithm. But that shouldn't be a big deal. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @sharethis check out this other answer I wrote which may be able to help you http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50023/how-can-i-prevent-seams-from-showing-up-on-objects-using-lower-mipmap-levels/50037#50037

Comment: @sharethis As a more practical solution, you could avoid atlasing altogether. Since your textures are already PoT, you won't be wasting memory by storing them separately. You will just have a small performance penalty when switching textures, but if you batch your draw calls sorted by texture, you will hardly feel this problem.

Comment: @sharethis Texture arrays are not available in all platforms, but using separate textures is. If you draw all the triangles that share the same texture at the same time, you don't have to do multitexturing, and the entire game would even work on GL 1.1/DirectX 7 hardware. Even with tens of thousands of triangles you won't see a performance hit on modern hardware (even mobile)

Comment: @PandaPajama. In my special use case, atlasing is the only practical solution to me. I explained that in other comments, but back to the topic now: For testing I generated custom mipmaps which are just green. There shouldn't be any seems but they remain! I inserted a screenshot in the question.

Comment: @PandaPajama. I need all the different texture tiles on the same mesh. I could use multitexturing but not to that point I guess. Moreover don't want to (can't) change the renderer, and it doesn't support multitexturing or texture arrays at the moment. Please see my other comment above.

Comment: @sharethis Don't try to fix it by changing settings. You will have this problem if you mix atlasing with mipmapping because that't what's supposed to happen. If you decided you really needed atlasing, then don't use mipmapping. If I were you I'd use mipmapping instead of atlasing though.

Comment: @PandaPajama. How is it possible to see black artifacts even if all mipmap levels are completely green? I cannot get that.

Comment: @sharethis Post the texture you're actually using, the sampling mode you're using (both the algorithm (nearest neighbor, bilinear, trilinear, aniso) and the extending mode (clamp, repeat, mirror) for both coordinates) and the UV coordinates you're using to draw those polygons and I'll probably be able to explain why you're seeing those black lines.

Comment: I am not using an image file but generate the pixel data in the source code. The texture parameters are `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` and `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. But I found a solution using custom mipmaps and nearest mipmap filter as explained in the answer I wrote.

Comment: For some reason I thought that this half-pixel padding for texture coordinates is already made for us by OpenGL automatically and we need to make this padding by hand only in Direct3D. The link in the post is also about Direct3D. [Here](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/) is another post saying that OpenGL and Direct3D > 9 already solve this proving my point. Not sure if I can believe it or not.

Comment: @vbo: A library that makes such corrections would be buggy. Texture coordinates are texture coordinates and should be interpreted as such. What I do know is that if you use point filtering (not bilinear or any other type of interpolation), and you sample at the exact point where texels intersect, you will usually get the texel at the bottom right.

Comment: OK. Another question is about this equation: `(x + 0.5) / tex_width`. Why you are always using `+ 0.5`? From your picture it looks like you need to use `+ 0.5` for e.g. left side of textured object and `- 0.5` right side. Like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6051557/539686). Could you please clarify this a bit?

Comment: ... couldn't you just set the minimum (maximum?) mip level to avoid bleeding?

Answer (score 19):

One option that'll be a lot easier than fiddling with mipmaps and adding texture coordinate fuzz factors is to use a texture array. Texture arrays are similar to 3d textures, but with no mipmapping in the 3rd dimension, so they're ideal for texture atlases where the "subtextures" are all the same size.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture

Comment: If they're available, they're a much better solution - you get other features as well, like wrapping textures, that you miss with atlases.

Comment: @JariKomppa. I do not want to use texture arrays because that way I would have extra shaders for the terrain. Since the engine I write should be as general as possible I do not want to make this exception. Is there a way to create one shader that can handle both, texture arrays and single textures?

Comment: @sharethis Dismissing unambiguously superiour technical solutions because you want to be "general" is a recipe for failure. If you write a game, don't write an engine.

Comment: @SamHocevar. I am writing an engine and my project is about a specific architecture were components are fully decoupled. So the form component shouldn't take care of the terrain component which should only provide standard buffers and a standard texture.

Comment: @sharethis OK. I was somehow misled by the "In my game" part of the question.

Comment: @SamHocevar. That's my fault. My engine is used by my game which implements the terrain thing. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: Texture Arrays aren't supported by GL ES 2 or below. They will be supported in GL ES 3, but very few devices support it yet (as of July 2013).

Comment: @danijar Then you are deliberately limiting yourself. I used to have that perspective as well: that software must be built of generic components. But that is actually a recipe for inefficient software in many cases. What you actually want is to design the fastest code, and *then* figure out how to split up that code into components. Not design components and then figure out how to tape them together to make something fast.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the issue could be caused by MSAA. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488465/160539) and the [linked article](http://www.opengl.org/img/uploads/pipeline/pipeline_003.pdf):

> "when you turn on MSAA, it then becomes possible for the shader to get
>   executed for samples that are inside the pixel area, but outside of
>   the triangle area"

The solution is to use centroid sampling. If you are calculating the wrapping of the texture coordinates in a vertex shader, moving that logic to the fragment shader could also fix the issue.

Comment: As I already wrote in another comment I have no working video card at the moment so I cannot check if that is the actual problem. I will do so as soon as I can.

Comment: I disabled hardware antialiasing but the bleeding still remains. I already do the texture looking in the fragment shader.

Comment: thanks! using `glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic, and I had a similar problem to the topic.

I had my texture coordinates just fine, but by lerping the camera position (which changed my element's positions) like so:

```
public static void tween(Camera cam, Direction dir, Vec2 buffer, Vec2 start, Vec2 end) {
    if(step > steps) {
        tweening = false;
        return;
    }

    final float alpha = step/steps;

    switch(dir) {
    case UP:
    case DOWN:
        buffer = new Vec2(start.getX(), Util.lerp(start.getY(), (float)end.getY(), alpha));
        cam.getPosition().set(buffer);
        break;
    case LEFT:
    case RIGHT:
        buffer = new Vec2(Util.lerp(start.getX(), end.getX(), alpha), start.getY());
        cam.getPosition().set(buffer);
        break;
    }

    step += 1;
}
```

The whole problem was Util.lerp() returns a float or double. This was bad because the camera was translating off-grid and causing some weird issues with texture snippets that where > 0 in X and > 0 in Y.

TLDR: don't tween or anything using floats