# XNA seams between 3d primitives in tiled terrain

Tags: xna, 3d, tiles, terrain

Every time I draw two primitives side by side, in this case two quads, I always get this seam-like tearing effect right along the sides of them. I'd like to think there is just an easy fix, but the only way I can think of would be reworking my indices, which I think would compromise my ability to draw textures. If anyone reading this can think of any fix, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways you can fix this.

1. You can apply a [half pixel offset](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/) to the corners, to make sure you have UVs that point to the center of a texel.
2. You can change your sampling mode to POINT sampling, for Mag, Min, Mip, AddressU and AddressV sampler states, like "untitled" mentioned.

Comment: See this SO post for more details http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-can-i-avoid-sampling-artifacts-from-adjacent-tiles-in-my-texture-atlas/49585#49585

Answer (score 0):

That looks more like a graphical artifact stemming from the texture that you are applying. It would be good if you gave some more information about how you are defining the quads, what vertex structure you are using and what effect you are using to render the quads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a texture atlas, What sampler states are you using?
Try using magfilter = POINT, minfilter = POINT, mipfilter = POINT, AddressU = WRAP, AddressV = WRAP