# Wrong UV mapping when using small textures and positions

Tags: textures, ogre, uv-mapping

I am using a really small texture (64x64) and when I use it as a UV map on my mesh, there are some incomplete lines from the color of the other side of the UV map rendered as well (in this case, white.)

The model was made in Blender, and it is rendered without this error. I set absolute coordinates, so the UV coordinates are multiple of 1.0 (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, etc.) I am using Ogre as renderer

This is the UV map:

[image: uv map]

Image with error:

[image: uv error]

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-to-avoid-texture-bleeding-in-a-texture-atlas/49584#49584

Comment: @msell I disagree, it looks more like a bad seam too me

Comment: @ratchetfreak Oops, I was supposed to link to the whole question, not just to a single answer.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Pacha: Set the mipmap level of your textures to be 1. That should get rid of this issue.

Comment: @Pacha: You could also try setting `tex_address_mode` to `clamp`; http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_17.html#tex_005faddress_005fmode