# Libgdx, lines between tiles

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make smooth following camera using this algorithm:

```
camera.position.add((pos.x - camera.position.x) * 1.2f * deltaTime, (pos.y - camera.position.y) * 1.2f * deltaTime, 0);
```

It works fine(camera movements are smooth), but when I move the player appears this artifacts:
[image: Before the movement]

[image: After the movement]

Player move() function:

```
moveX(SPEED  * deltaTime);
```

```
protected void moveX (float amount) {
        float newX = pos.x + amount;
        if (!map.doesRectCollideWithMap(newX, pos.y, getWidth(), getHeight()))
            pos.x = newX;
    }
```

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago and it turned out to be caused by texture bleeding ([read up on it here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-to-avoid-texture-bleeding-in-a-texture-atlas)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Set texture filtering of TiledMap to Nearest.
2. Add 2px padding to your tileset.
3. Draw yor sprites 1px broeder each direction.
4. Profit!